# How can I make custom urls like mywebsite.com/movie_title rather than mywebsite.com/movie?id=9282

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I am building a website using java and google app engine. I need to create urls like www.mywebsite.com/the_dark_knight_rises

when a user goes to that url info is pulled from my database (mysql) about the movie The Dark Knight Rises and is displayed

The problem I have is

1) I don't know how to go on about making these dynamic urls, since my database contains 500k movies so i don't think i can make them manually

2) how do I pull info about that record. I got an idea to take the /the_dark_knight_rises part of the url replace the underscores with spaces and try to seach my database like `select * from table where title like 'the dark knight rises'` but i am not sure if this is the best solution or how to get that part of the url

Any help/directions are welcome

Comment: You can parse the name from the HttpServletRequest.getRequestedUrl() or HttpRequest.getServletPath(). I'm working on a similiar project where each entity has an UUID. I made a servlet which maps all UUIDs and fetch the data out of the database.

Comment: Just a side note, **please** make sure you use [`PreparedStatements`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for this, you **never** want to allow user input to go unsanatized into a database query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Use [getPathInfo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo()) or [getRequestURI()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI()) to extract path from current url

2) Remove underscores from path and construct movie title

3) Make database call

4) Show movei if exists or show 404 if not.

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is just to do this for SEO or readability purposes, you could always serve the urls as www.website.com/movie_name_in_text?id=abc123

This allows you to do a get by id on the database, but surfaces textual information for people and bots.

You should also probably look into using a Web MVC framework, such as [Spring](http://projects.spring.io/spring-framework/), [thundr](http://3wks.github.io/thundr/) or similar. They can handle this type of data binding automatically, rather than requiring you to program to the low level servlet api.

---

Disclaimer, I'm a maintainer of thundr